# how to access one specific document (in firestore) to display after ontap operation in flutter list tile

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore collection (countries) and I need to show only one document in it after I press on the tile but whatever I write inside the ontap function is giving me various errors. what do I do?
here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:vola1/pageShow.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:async/async.dart';

class test extends StatelessWidget {
  const test({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('countries')
            // .doc('nW9L4LGpn2MZVyiTyUII')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot) {
          if (querySnapshot.hasError) return Text('has some error');
          if (querySnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            // if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data.. please wait..');
            final list = querySnapshot.data.docs;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(list[index]['name']),
                    subtitle: Text(list[index]['description']),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    leading: Image.network(
                      list[index]['image'],
                      height: 200,
                      width: 80,
                    ),
                    onTap: () => {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => pageShow(list[index]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    },
                  ),
                  color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                );
              },
              itemCount: list.length,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 111, 82, 0.8),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

this is code of the page I am navigating to

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:async/async.dart';

class pageShow extends StatelessWidget {
  const pageShow(list(index), {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('countries').get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data.. please wait..');
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                snapshot.data['name'],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              Text(
                snapshot.data['description'],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              Text(
                snapshot.data['cuisine'],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              Text(
                snapshot.data['tradition'],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 111, 82, 0.8),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

after pressing on the tile I want it to display all the contents of the specific document in firestore.it would be very heplful.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you don't need to use .snapshots() when fetching a single document. You can try the code below. Also I would suggest to keep the document ID as the country name in lower case so that you can use the query below.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('countries')
    .doc("countryName")
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
        //Set the relevant data to variables as needed
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist on the database');
      }
    });
```

Here's another sample from the [FlutterFire Documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#one-time-read)

However, if you do no want the country name as the document ID then you would have to store the country name in the doc as a field (lower case preferred as queries are case sensitive). Then you can make a request as follows:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('countries')
  .where('countryName', isEqualTo: "theCountryNameUserClickedOn")
  .get()
```

Make sure to add the countryName field in the document in Firestore.

Comment: actually I want to show the all the contents of the document after the user taps on the tile there are just two documents there now but i will be adding more in there, I just cant figure out how to show the data related to specific country ontap. do make a new page and then give the navigator push to that page in ontap? but it is showing every single thing about all the documents and I don't want that to happen. could you please help.

Comment: @KalyaniMalokar I'm not getting getting. Can you please share a sample output? I mean are you trying to get a document based on value of a field in it. But only 1 matching document?

Comment: as you see in the app interface picture I have two countries and the data of these countries is stored in two different documents in one collection in firestore so, now the problem is that when i tap on the tile which has the picture and description of the country I want it to open to a new page which show data from that specific document of the country.  @Dharmaraj

Comment: @KalyaniMalokar can you please share screenshot of complete document? You need a field with country name in it.

Comment: @KalyaniMalokar I've updated the answer. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: I edited the question and the code , it is still not working as I expected and i am not sure how to get the country name the user clicked on and display the whole document contents according to it. i checked many YouTube videos and documents but I cant seem to find a solution for this. Could Please take look at the edited code ? @Dharmaraj

Comment: Hi, did you ever find out how to do this? I am having the exact same issue right now! Thank you